# Brave stone heart forth Barksdale tower

Tags: knowledge, geography, poetry, haiku

This is a puzzle-[monoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku_in_English#One_line_.28monoku.29). The answer is a place in the British Isles.

> brave
>
> stone
>
> heart
>
> forth
>
> Barksdale
>
> tower

Comment: Sorry @moonbutt74, [ICTYBTIHTKY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuE_jqYNi3c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i will risk the smackdown on this,

I will start with my answer but nailing the monoku word by word will take a bit.

**Answer:**

> [The National Wallace Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_Monument)
>
>  brave heart would be funny if you meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_Monument#/media/File:William_Wallace_Statue.JPG) which had to be put in a cage.

Though i think you are looking for a more specific point or specific example among the [many](http://www.thesocietyofwilliamwallace.com/williamwallacemonuments.htm)

**On the monoku;**

I broke it down from,

> Brave stone heart forth Barksdale tower

To,

> Brave heart stone tower forth Barksdale

brave heart would be funny if you meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_Monument#/media/File:William_Wallace_Statue.JPG) which had to be put in a cage.

stone tower is umm, a stone tower?

Forth Valley is part of the view.

Barksdale is where I'm stuck if any of the above is correct or even close as there is apparently no geographical feature/location associated with that "name" in the British Isles. Searching i pull up hits for tower houses and an air force base in Louisiana.

So i don't really dig on pop culture so my final guess on Barksdale would be the character from the wire, which could be a sneaky word-play clue to stand-in for the cage around the statue.

Comment: There you go! Yes, I did mean the thing that had to be put in a cage. :)

So just Barksdale to go then.......

Comment: @A E It's sad though, isn't it? Wallace was a great hero. I'm not even Scottish and i was pissed when i saw it. Better to destroy that thing than have an image of a freedom fighter associated with a cage.

Comment: Ah, I don't think it's sad. My interpretation of it is that the local residents didn't like Mel Gibson very much, and didn't want WW to be thought of as him. Which is quite inspiring in a way! :)

Comment: Good way to look at it, Barksdale is driving me mad!!!!

Comment: That bit's definitely 'trivia'. GIYF on that one, or someone else will just know it. It's the kind of fact you either know or you don't, there's no real way (other than internet searching) to work it out.

Comment: @A E , I found an article on [University of Mississippi 2013 Barksdale award winners traveling to Scotland](http://news.olemiss.edu/barksdale-award-winners-named/) what does GIYF mean?

Comment: sorry - means 'google is your friend'. ah no, it's not quite as obscure as that. just a pop culture reference.

Comment: Could **[this](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=43523149)** be relevant?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain thanks, i had looked at that during my search but A E says it's a pop culture reference, although i am likely thinking in American terms which would be out of context?

Comment: The character from The Wire - what was the name of his gang again? Who did he work for? ;)

Comment: @A E Apparently the Barksdale Organization but i still don't get the reference. ?

Comment: Perhaps Avon Barkdale? Legend has it that William Wallace and his followers hid in Wallace Cave by the river Avon.

Comment: Ahh, okay, the first name of the character hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: So very close https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_(The_Wire)